# Stop prettier from formatting min files?

Tags: prettier

Is there any way I can universally stop prettier from formatting .min files in all of my projects without individually whitelisting every one?

Comment: What IDE or editor are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: This might me helpful: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `.prettierignore` file that looks something like this:

```
*.min.*
```

However, you still will need to do this for every project. There is no way to "globally" set prettier rules, as Thorn0 explains in [this](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/8094#issuecomment-616444163) comment.